# How to read 3x3xN coordinates string into matlab array efficently

Tags: json, matlab

I have a MATLAB script that takes a JSON that was created by myself in a remote server and contains a long list of `3x3xN` coordinates e.g. for `N=1`:

```
str = '[1,2,3.14],[4,5.66,7.8],[0,0,0],';
```

I want to avoid string splitting it, is there any approach to use `strread` or similar to read this 3×3×N tensor?

It's a multi-particle system and `N` can be large, though I have enough memory to store it all at once in the memory.

Any suggestion of how to format the array string in the JSON is very welcome as well.

Comment: I am nto an expert (by far) in this stuff, but if N can be large, you may need to consider not sending the data as text, but as binary instead.

Comment: Agreed with @AnderBiguri; does said server have an API of some kind which allows direct access to the binary data?

Comment: Also, what's your MATLAB version? Because in R2016b there's built-in support for JSON via `jsonencode` and `jsondecode`. If you have an older version, you may be interested in [this post](http://blogs.mathworks.com/pick/2015/04/24/parsing-json-files/), [this FEX submission](https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/33381-jsonlab--a-toolbox-to-encode-decode-json-files) or [this one](https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/20565-json-parser), [this post](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/json-matlab-integration) on undocumented MATLAB, ......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can guarantee the format is always the same, I think it's easiest, safest and fastest to use `sscanf`:

```
fmt  = '[%f,%f,%f],[%f,%f,%f],[%f,%f,%f],';
data = reshape(sscanf(str, fmt), 3, 3).';
```

Depending on the rest of your data (how is that "`N`" represented?), you might need to  adjust that `reshape`/`transpose`.

**EDIT** 
Based  on your comment, I think this will solve your problem quite efficiently:

```
% Strip unneeded concatenation characters
str(str == ',') = ' ';
str(str == ']' | str == '[') = [];

% Reshape into workable dimensions
data = permute( reshape(sscanf(str, '%f '), 3,3,[]), [2 1 3]);
```

As noted by rahnema1, you can avoid the `permute` and/or character removal by adjusting your JSON generators to spit out the data column-major and without brackets, but you'll have to ask yourself these questions:

1. whether that is really worth the effort, considering that this code right here is already quite tiny and pretty efficient
2. whether other applications are going to use the JSON interface, because in essence you're de-generalizing the JSON output just to fit your processing script on the other end. I think that's a pretty bad design practice, but oh well.

Just something to keep in mind:

- emitting 500k values in binary is about 34 MB
- doing the same in ASCII is about 110 MB

Now depending a bit on your connection speed, I'd be getting **really** annoyed **really** quickly because every little test run takes about 3 times as long as it should be taking :)

So if an API call straight to the raw data is not possible, I would at least base64 that data in the JSON.

Comment: N can be around 500K

Comment: @0x90, OK but what I meant was, I see only 1×3×3. Do you have `N` of those strings, or does the actual data continue in the same string somehow, or...? Can you post a snippet of your JSON for `N = 3` or so?

Comment: Simply `str` N times. N=3:

`str = [1,2,3.14],[4,5.66,7.8],[0,0,0],[1,2,3.14],[4,5.66,7.8],[0,0,0],[1,2,3.14],[4,5.66,7.8],[0,0,0],';` 

note I can format the json as I wish. It is a list of 3-dim object each has 3 components, so you have 9 coordinates per each object

Answer (score 2):

You can use `eval` function:

```
str = '[1,2,3.14],[4,5.66,7.8],[0,0,0],';
result=permute(reshape(eval(['[' ,str, ']']),3,3,[]),[2 1 3])
```

result =

```
1.00000   2.00000   3.14000
4.00000   5.66000   7.80000
0.00000   0.00000   0.00000
```

Using `eval` all elements concatenated  to create a row vector. Then row vector reshaped to a 3d array. Since in MATLAB elements are placed in matrix columnwise it is required to `permute` the array so each 3*3 matrix are trasposed.

**note1**: There is no need to place `[]` in jSON string so you can use `str2num` instead of eval :

```
 result=permute(reshape(str2num(str),3,3,[]),[2 1 3])
```

**note2**:
if you save data columnwise there is no need to permute:

```
str='1 4 0 2 5.66 0 3.14 7.8 0';
result=reshape(str2num(str),3,3,[])
```

**Update:** As  [Ander Biguri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1485872/ander-biguri)  and [excaza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2748311/excaza)  noted about security an speed issues related to `eval` and `str2num` and after [Rody Oldenhuis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1085062/rody-oldenhuis) 's  suggestion about using `sscanf` I tested 3 methods in Octave:

```
a=num2str(rand(1,60000));

disp('-----SSCANF---------')
tic
sscanf(a,'%f ');
toc

disp('-----STR2NUM---------')
tic
str2num(a);
toc

disp('-----STRREAD---------')
tic
strread(a,'%f ');
toc
```

and here is the result:

```
-----SSCANF---------
Elapsed time is 0.0344398 seconds.
-----STR2NUM---------
Elapsed time is 0.142491 seconds.
-----STRREAD---------
Elapsed time is 0.515257 seconds.
```

So it is more secure and faster to use `sscanf`, in your case:

```
str='1 4 0 2 5.66 0 3.14 7.8 0';
result=reshape(sscanf(str,'%f '),3,3,[])
```

or

```
str='1, 4, 0, 2, 5.66, 0, 3.14, 7.8, 0';
result=reshape(sscanf(str,'%f,'),3,3,[])
```

Comment: Please consider `N>>1` and efficiency. Reformatting the JSON is possible.

Comment: Just be very very very very careful with this eval. If a harmful command comes in a form of a string, you will evaluate it.

Comment: `str2num` runs `eval` internally so there really isn't much functional difference other than input validation (protection).